# jQuery TypeError: $ is not a function - But how to continue to use $?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Trying to get around this error here, which is problematic for me...

Basically, I am defining a variable as an object from the start.  The object has functions that utilize jQuery, but I need to set properties of the object during page load (which seems that I need to set them before the jQuery document is ready perhaps?)

Anyways, here is a .js file that loads in the head of the page using

```
var MyObject = {

    Property1 : null,
    Property2 : null,
    Property3 : null,
    Property4 : 0,

    Initialize: function() {
        // Do some code in here...
        if ($('#some-element').length)
        {
            MyObject.Property1 = $('#some-element').data('property');
            $('#some-element').click(MyObject.On_ClickProperty1);
        }


    },
    On_Click_Property1: function() {
        alert('You Clicked ' + MyObject.Property1);

        if (MyObject.Property2 !== null)
            alert('Property2 = ' + MyObject.Property2);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(MyObject.Initialize);
```

This is a very small example here.  But now I would like to set MyObject.Property2 on the actual page somewhere (In the Body) and have it update, and that should work fine, since `Initialize` function doesn't actually run until Document.Ready.  So I put something like this in the body of the Document...

```
<script>
MyObject.Property2 = 'This Is Property 2';
</script>
```

The problem I get now is an on Page Load...
`TypeError: $ is not a function`

Now, if I wrap the .js file with the following code like so:

```
(function($){
var MyObject = {

    Property1 : null,
    Property2 : null,
    Property3 : null,
    Property4 : 0,

    Initialize: function() {
        // Do some code in here...
        if ($('#some-element').length)
        {
            MyObject.Property1 = $('#some-element').data('property');
            $('#some-element').click(MyObject.On_ClickProperty1);
        }


    },
    On_Click_Property1: function() {
        alert('You Clicked ' + MyObject.Property1);

        if (MyObject.Property2 !== null)
            alert('Property2 = ' + MyObject.Property2);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(MyObject.Initialize);
})(jQuery);
```

I no longer see this error, however, `MyObject.Property2` is not being set and the alert for Property2 gives null.

How can I accomplish this properly?  So that I don't get `$` typeError, and I can still use `$` (NOT `jQuery` within the Property functions), and I can actually set the value of `Property2` before the alert of MyObject.Property2 shows up??

Comment: Sanity check: is the jQuery library loaded at the time this code runs? (no 404s, etc. in the console). Your custom .js file should be listed after the jQuery library in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Yes, the custom.js file is listed after the jquery.min.js file is loaded, all in the head.  And the inline script for setting `MyObject.Property2` is within the body tag.  The first method gives error, but properly sets the variable, while the 2nd method gives no error, but doesn't set the variable.  Which method is correct here?

Comment: Neither one of these is my desired end result.  Both of which have only half of what I need it to do...  No errors, and set the variable...

Comment: put the `(function($){})(jQuery)` in the `Initialize: function() {}` and `On_Click_Property1: function() {}` , not outside the object declaration

Comment: Why does your custom `.js` file have to be in the `<head>` of the page?

Comment: could you provide your html code here that include that js file

Comment: @RedMercury It doesn't have to be in the head, but that is how I'm loading it.  How should I be loading it?

Comment: `MyObject.Property2 is not being set` is because that you declare it in the `function($){}`, so that the object is only usable in the function. see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: ah... you override your jquery function $ to your parameter $

Comment: So, how to change this code to still use jQuery with `$` char and set `MyObject.Property2`?  I would like to use `$` within the `MyObject` property functions still, if possible...  How to load it so that this can be done?

Comment: just remove parameter $

Comment: @Newbee Dev - Can you be more specific

Comment: just remove the "$" in this code (function($){ because you are overriding the jquery $ function

Comment: I removed `$` in that code, and it nows says `$` is not defined and gives a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have jquery loaded in no conflict mode. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/
You can assign $ back to jquery if you are not using $ for any other library. Add below on header before `var MyObject`.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Also you can try loading that script file in footer. Here is how I would do it. 
On header I would initialize empty object globally.

```
var MyObject = {};
```

Then you could do

```
(function($){
  MyObject.property1 = null;
  MyObject.Initialize = function () {
    //your codes
  }
  //other lines here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There are too many functions that are properties of the object.  I gave you a small example.  I need this to be within it's own file.  I can't output on the page.  It would be too much to be outputted on the actual page, and besides, this object gets used on other pages.

Comment: I need to set the defaults in a .js file, but be able to set some of the properties of the object on a page by page level, when needed and it should update it.  How to do this?

Comment: Placing `var $ = jQuery.conflict();` without true did it for me.  putting in true parameter made all other scripts break.  Thanks :)